# How to determine the sign of $q^{n+1} - q^n$ in different cases

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Today in math class we saw how to determine whether a sequence is strictly increasing, strictly decreasing, or constant. I had to express $u_{n+1} - u_{n}$ for a geometric sequence $(u_{n})_{n \geq 0}$ with common ratio $q$.
Using my lesson, I worked out this expression:
$u_{n+1} - u_{n} = u_{0}(q^{n+1} - q^n)$
We were also told that we could determine whether $(u_{n})$ was decreasing or increasing by studying the sign of $u_{n+1} - u_{n}$, therefore it depends on the sign of the product of $u_{0}$ and $q^{n+1} - q^n$.
My question is: **how do I determine the sign of $q^{n+1} - q^n$ when $q > 1$ and when $0 < q < 1$ by demonstrating it?**
I am not excellent at math so I'd like to get your help, thank you in advance. :)

---

Sorry if there is any syntax or vocabulary mistake, I'm not an English native.

Comment: Hint: The expression is equal to $q^n(q-1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just factor

$$q^{n+1}-q^n=q^n(q-1)$$

and recall when the product of two numbers is positive.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it was quite basic...